# Comments from vbulletin topic

Tags: comments

I have a WordPress site and a forum that runs vBulletin. Each article I post on the website is automatically posted as a thread on a specific forum category (using the website RSS feed). Now, I have one questions for those that are far more knowledgeable in WP:

Is there a simple solution that would allow me to list the thread replies on the forum as comments in the corresponding WordPress article?